# Add new parent to selected node(s) xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to add a new parent to selected nodes while retaining all other structure and attributes.

Original structure (attributes and other children removed from sample)

```
<document>
<pages>
    <page>
        <stream>
            <block>
                <table/> <!-- any number or tables or groups can exist in a block -->
                <group/>
            </block>
        </stream>
    </page>
</pages>
</document>
```

Requested result:

```
<document>
<pages>
    <page>
        <stream>
            <block>
                <category> <!-- NEW PARENT, only 1 table per category-->
                    <table/> 
                </category>
                <category> <!-- NEW PARENT, only 1 group per category -->
                    <group/>
                </category>
            </block>
        </stream>
    </page>
</pages>
</document>
```

This seems like such a trivial problem, but I can't seem to figure it out or find a solution online.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), with one extra template matching `block/*` that then wraps each match in `<category></category>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="block/*">
        <category>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </category>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. This does the job. It did not work against my real document and I realized it was a namespace issue. Thanks again.